# Python Selenium Automatic Follow Instagram

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

This script doesn't follow on Instagram why?

```
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
"GO INSTAGRAM PAGE FOR LOGIN"
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=it')

sleep(2)
"ID AND PASSWORD"
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('id')
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('password')
"CLICK BUTTON AND OPEN INSTAGRAM"

good_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span/button').click()

sleep(2)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")

"GO TO PAGE FOR FOLLOW"
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/test/")  
time.sleep(30)  
"FOLLOW (DON'T WORK)"

follow = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/span/span[1]/button').click()
```

Comment: dude i think the xpath you are using for the follow button is wrong, can you double check if you copied it correctly, because i get //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/a/button

Comment: Don't work mate.

Comment: strange..because it works for me..i don't have an account on instagram but it do take me to the login page...please try this...options = webdriver.Chrome(path to the chrome driver exe) options.get('http://instagram.com/test') options.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/a/button').click()

Comment: or i think the xpath might change after login..so try with class name.....options.find_element_by_class_name('BY3EC').click()

Comment: thank you now work.

Comment: Do you know class name for unfollow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ActionChains` when click on an element. So your code will be something like this:

```
good_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span/button')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(good_elem).click().perform()
```

and for follow button, the code will be something like this:

```
follow = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/span/span[1]/button')
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(follow).click().perform()
```